# How does this matrix multiply work in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, matrix, group-by, sum

Full disclosure, I'm a noob at SQL

Given two sparce matrices A and B, defined as:

A(row_number, column_number, value) and B(row_number, column_number, value)

I don't understand how this query represents the multiplication of the two matrices:

```
SELECT A.row_number, B.column_number, SUM(A.value * B.value)
FROM A, B
WHERE A.column_number = B.row_number
GROUP BY A.row_number, B.column_number
```

My confusion lies in the SUM syntax and the GROUP BY / SELECT syntax

So for my GROUP BY / SELECT confusion, I don't understand why the expressions

A.row_number and B.column_number are necessary after the SELECT statement

Why do we have to specify that when we're already using SELECT and WHERE ? To me that seems like we're saying we want to SELECT using those expressions (A.row_number and B.column_number) even though we're given back a table from WHERE already. Would it not make more sense to just say SELECT * ? I'm assuming that GROUP BY just requires you to type out the expressions it uses in the SELECT statement, but I don't know for sure.

For the SUM, I just want to clarify, the SUM is only using the A.value and the B.value from whatever is returned by the WHERE correct? Otherwise, you would be multiplying all A.value with all B.value.

Clarifying either of these would be immensely helpful. Thank you!

Comment: It would help to have definition of tables A and B. It seems it is: row_number, column_number, value.

Comment: good point, you're correct, I'll add that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
create table A
(   column_number int,
    row_number int,
    value int
);
create table B
(   column_number int,
    row_number int,
    value int
);

insert A (column_number,row_number,value) values (1,1,1),(1,2,2),(2,1,3),(2,2,4);
insert B (column_number,row_number,value) values (1,1,10),(1,2,20),(2,1,30),(2,2,40);
```

Data with your old style (non explicit) join **without** aggregage or group by:

```
SELECT A.row_number as Ar, B.column_number as Bc,
A.value as Av,B.value as Bv,A.value*B.value as product
FROM A, B
WHERE A.column_number = B.row_number

+------+------+------+------+---------+
| Ar   | Bc   | Av   | Bv   | product |
+------+------+------+------+---------+
|    1 |    1 |    1 |   10 |      10 |
|    2 |    1 |    2 |   10 |      20 |
|    1 |    1 |    3 |   20 |      60 |
|    2 |    1 |    4 |   20 |      80 |
|    1 |    2 |    1 |   30 |      30 |
|    2 |    2 |    2 |   30 |      60 |
|    1 |    2 |    3 |   40 |     120 |
|    2 |    2 |    4 |   40 |     160 |
+------+------+------+------+---------+
```

Seeing the above, the below gets a little more clarity:

```
SELECT A.row_number, B.column_number,sum(A.value * B.value) as theSum
FROM A, B
WHERE A.column_number = B.row_number
GROUP BY A.row_number, B.column_number
+------------+---------------+--------+
| row_number | column_number | theSum |
+------------+---------------+--------+
|          1 |             1 |     70 |
|          1 |             2 |    150 |
|          2 |             1 |    100 |
|          2 |             2 |    220 |
+------------+---------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Giving table name after `SELECT` will identify which table to refer to. Mainly useful in the case where both tables have same column names.
2. `GROUP BY` will aggregate the data and display one record per grouped-by value. That is, in your case, you'll end up with only one record per row-column combination.

Answer (score 1):

By definition multiplication of two matrices A(n,m) and B(m,p) produces a matrix C(n,p).

So the SQL for multiplication should return same data structure as was used for storage of A and B, which is three columns:

- row_number
- column_number
- value

, with one value per (row, column) combination.

This is why you need first two in the `group by` clause.

`WHERE` clause is independent from `SELECT`. First is responsible for getting the right records, second for getting the right columns.